# Problems with video graphics in games

Tags: graphics, games

Sorry for the not accurate title , but it is easier to see this image rather then explain:
[image]

I get this strange view for most of the games. I really don't know what is the source for the error, i get it also on: Left4dead2 and Dota2. Maybe opengl?

Thanks for help and all the answers.

Result from `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 VGA`:

```
    01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GK107 [GeForce GT 630 OEM] [10de:0fc2] (rev a1)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:83e2]
Kernel driver in use: nouveau
```

Comment: could you please add the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 VGA` to your question.

Comment: @JohnnyD. Added the result from `lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 VGA`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see you're not using `proprietary/binary` driver for your video card you're using an open-source driver `nouveau` and bugs are acceptable it cannot guarantee 100% of reproduction for your video card, all the bugs you can submit to Launchpad if you wish to stay with `nouveau` you might consider adding [Xorg-edgers ppa](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ppa) for the latest `nouveau` bug fixes and updates you can find ppa detailed description in Launchpad. Or consider installing `proprietary/binary` driver for your video card.